# Upload action.json file of Google actions via API

Tags: actions-on-google

I upload my google action file via  Gactions CLi but is there any way to upload google action' action.json file via API.?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to say, but I have tried to figure out and answer.
I think you are trying to ask us about how to upload JSON file in api.ai? If yes then you have to follow these steps.
1. Go to api.ai
2. Click on 3 dots beside create intent option.
3. Click on upload intent.  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F08mt.jpg
4. Choose file and upload.

There's one more method.
1. Go to settings of your agent.
2. Go to export/import
3. Click import from zip
4. Select your zip file and upload it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it by coding. You just need to use the Dialogueflow client api.

For more information please refer below link.

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/dialogflow/v2